# Automatic KeyStone Correction of RPI CAM

Tags: raspicam

I'm requiring a camera to be pretty close to a screen (100 mm perhaps) and off to the side of the screen so it isn't in the way. Easy enough except of course I'd get severe keystone errors. So my question is what would be the best way to correct those errors in a video stream?
Even better could it be automatic if the distance from the screens surface (Z axis only, X and Y remain constant) is known.
A python options would be good as I'm running it on the RPI but completely open to suggestions as to software (Edited in response to a question by Andyroo)

Thanks...

Comment: You may want to detail what streaming and / or capture software you are using by editing the question to give folk a clue...

Answer (score 1):

Most projects you'll find are aimed at driving projectors which lack built-in keystone correction. I've seen a generic [xrandr keystone helper](https://github.com/qurn/xrandr-keystone-helper) and a Pi-specific [ofxPiMapper](https://github.com/kr15h/ofxPiMapper) you may want to look at.

Speaking of direct video stream transformations, I would check out `AviSynth`: I bet there are perspective correction plugins, but I'm too far from the subject to recommend something specifically.

Comment: Thanks Dimitry I shall go and do some reading on those suggestions..